# Haskell: recursively convert hex string to integer?

Tags: haskell, recursion, hex, type-conversion

For my homework assignment, I need to convert a hexadecimal string to a base-10 integer using a recursive function (with as many helper methods as necessary).

This is what I've got so far:

```
-- Question 1, part (c):
hexChar :: Char -> Integer
hexChar ch
    | ch == '0' = 0
    | ch == '1' = 1
    | ch == '2' = 2
    | ch == '3' = 3
    | ch == '4' = 4
    | ch == '5' = 5
    | ch == '6' = 6
    | ch == '7' = 7
    | ch == '8' = 8
    | ch == '9' = 9
    | ch == 'A' = 10
    | ch == 'B' = 11
    | ch == 'C' = 12
    | ch == 'D' = 13
    | ch == 'E' = 14
    | ch == 'F' = 15
    | otherwise     = 0

parseHex :: String -> Integer
parseHex hxStr 
    | length hxStr /= 0 = (hexChar(last(hxStr)))+(10*parseHex(init(hxStr)))
    | otherwise         = 0
```

However, this does not produce the correct results.
Does anyone know of the correct way to do this?

Comment: Hint: Try your function with the input '10' and using the (wrong) result, try to figure out where your error is.

Comment: I was off by one character. Multiplying it by 16 now and the function is 100% working :)

Comment: btw, you don't need so many parentheses, this should work fine: `| length hxStr /= 0 = hexChar (last hxStr) + 16*parseHex (init hxStr)`

Comment: try using `not (null hxStr)` instead of `length hxStr /= 0`. This is better, since it just checks if there is any elements in `hxStr`. Haskell strings are implemented as linked lists, so `length hxStr` takes time proportional to the length of `hxStr`. In contrast `not (null hxStr)` takes constant time to compute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are really close. your error is on this line:

```
    | length hxStr /= 0 = (hexChar(last(hxStr)))+(10*parseHex(init(hxStr)))
```

Think about why you are multiplying by 10. Remember ... Hexadecimal is base 16.

Answer (score 5):

Now that you got the right answer, you should consider the style. Using pattern matching, this looks clearer already:

```
parseHex :: String -> Integer
parseHex [] = 0
parseHex hxStr = (hexChar(last(hxStr)))+(16*parseHex(init(hxStr)))
```

And it's also more efficient, as you don't need to evalute `length hxStr` (which is O(N)) at each recursive call to decide which case applies. Total runtime goes from O(N**2) to O(N).

It looks even better when you drop some parentheses, as groovy suggested:

```
parseHex :: String -> Integer
parseHex [] = 0
parseHex hxStr = hexChar (last hxStr) + 16 * parseHex (init hxStr))
```

It's unfortunate that you can't pattern match on `hxStr` right away because you need `init` and `last` instead of `head` and `tail`. But you can mitigate that using `reverse` and a helper:

```
parseHex :: String -> Integer
parseHex hxStr = go (reverse hxStr)
    where go []     = 0
          go (x:xs) = hexChar x + 16 * parseHex xs
```

That last one may be just a matter of taste though. `hexChar` also becomes shorter:

```
hexChar '0' = 0
hexChar '1' = 1
...                  -- other cases here
hexChar _ = 0        -- 'otherwise' case; maybe throw an error instead?
```

Answer (score 4):

After the problem is solved, here a shorter way to write this:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

hexChar ch = fromMaybe (error $ "illegal char " ++ [ch]) $ 
    elemIndex ch "0123456789ABCDEF"

parseHex hex = foldl' f 0 hex where
    f n c = 16*n + hexChar c
```

Comment: Well, I mean, if you're going to allow library functions, why not go [straight to `readHex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Numeric.html#v:readHex)?

Comment: For learning purposes, of course.  If imports are forbidden, you can write `parseHex` using `foldl` (with the well-known drawbacks), and keep the original `hexChar` implementation.